# call jQuery plugin function using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-plugins

i spent a lot of time trying to call jQuery plugin function using angular. So far no success. I want to use fancybox(jQuery) plugin using angularJS.

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lukiux666/LyaespL1/ fiddle is set to jQuery 2.2.1 so you can see how it has to look, but i need the same using only angular.

I need to call this function jquery in angularjs:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancybox").fancybox(); 
 });
```

my last attempt was

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', [function() {

angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    angualr.element(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
}]);
```

I really need this to work, thank you so much in advance.

Comment: use  directives for initializing plugins

Comment: i have tried that, but i dont know how exactly to do it. I've read some examples, but still i don't understand how to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use angular directives, I change your fiddle and implement with directives,

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])

.directive('fancybox', [function() {
    function link($scope, $element){
        $element.fancybox();
    }
    return {
       restrict: 'AE',
       link: link
    }
}]);
```

look this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hv55dgv/2/)

Comment: setting FRAMEWORKS & EXTENSIONS --> AngularJS 1.4.8 and the code won't work. That is what im stuggling with.

Comment: @LukasRukštelis who said? what is the problem above code?

Comment: Yeah, I set it explicit, but in any case use directives for jquery plugins, and never use ready event inside angular controller or directive, because in link or controller functions elements already ready.

Comment: So is it ok to use jQuery for plugins when building web app on angularJS?

Comment: Yeah if angular equivalents not exists.

Comment: also there are fancybox module for angular check this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-fancybox-plus

Comment: Im finishing building a photo gallery app for my job apply, never worked on angular before or web development, so everything's a bit new.

Comment: I've worked on very large angular based project, and we're using a lot of js plugins like jison parser, semver, or jquery ui(drag and drop). There are no equivalents for this libs and plugins, so we make them directives like in my code.

Comment: i've noticed an interesting thing. The code works on fiddle, but wont work on localhost. Gives an error "$element.fancybox is not a function" at line $element.fancybox in .js file.